# Assertation failed image.depth() in blobFromImages

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to create a blob of multiple frames using blobFromImages in the dnn module.

```
def batch_process(self, frames):
    blob = cv.dnn.blobFromImages(frames, 1./255, (368, 368), (0, 0, 0), swapRB=False, crop=False)
    self.net.setInput(blob)
    out = self.net.forward()
    detected_points = np.zeros((frames.shape[0], 36))

    for i in range(frames.shape[0]):
        points = np.array([])
        for j in range(18):
            heatMap = out[i, j, :, :]
            _, conf, _, point = cv.minMaxLoc(heatMap)
            if conf > 0.1:
                points = np.append(points, [point[0], point[1]])
            else:
                points = np.append(points, [0, 0])
        detected_points[i] = points

    return detected_points
```

But when i call the function I get an error like this:-

```
OpenCV(3.4.1) Error: Assertion failed (image.depth() == 5) in blobFromImages, file /opt/opencv/modules/dnn/src/dnn.cpp
```

The blobFromImage() works fine on a similar single frame. **As far as I understand, blobFromImages() want an array of frames. Hence, I'm passing a numpy array of shape (32, 480, 640, 3) as parameter**. Can someone please help me find out what am I missing? I cannot seem to find examples using blobFromImages(). I'd want to use that as it might lessen my processing time than using blobFromImage().

Comment: Depth in terms of `cv::Mat` refers to the datatype of elements. Value of 5 corresponds to 32bit floating point. | See if giving it `np.float32(frames)` solves it.

Comment: Thank you, @DanMašek . That did solve it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First let's analyze the error message and translate it into something easy to understand.

```
Assertion failed (image.depth() == 5) in blobFromImages
```

Since this is coming from the C++ implementation of OpenCV, it is safe to assume that `image` is an instance of [`cv::Mat`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html) (we could inspect the source code to determine this). The documentation of [`cv::Mat::depth()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a8da9f853b6f3a29d738572fd1ffc44c0) says the following:

> Returns the depth of a matrix element.
>
> The method returns the identifier of the matrix element depth (the type of each individual channel). For example, for a 16-bit signed element array, the method returns `CV_16S`. A complete list of matrix types contains the following values:
>
> - `CV_8U` - 8-bit unsigned integers ( 0..255 )
> - `CV_8S` - 8-bit signed integers ( -128..127 )
> - `CV_16U` - 16-bit unsigned integers ( 0..65535 )
> - `CV_16S` - 16-bit signed integers ( -32768..32767 )
> - `CV_32S` - 32-bit signed integers ( -2147483648..2147483647 )
> - `CV_32F` - 32-bit floating-point numbers ( -FLT_MAX..FLT_MAX, INF, NAN )
> - `CV_64F` - 64-bit floating-point numbers ( -DBL_MAX..DBL_MAX, INF, NAN )

OK, so it's the datatype of each individual element in the array. To decipher which datatype the value of `5` represents (*hint: the above list is in ascending order and numbering starts at 0*), we can refer to the documentation of [Core HAL](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d1/d1b/group__core__hal__interface.html) where the values are listed.

```
#define     CV_32F   5
```

So, the error message says:

> I expected to get array of 32bit floats, but I got something else.

---

You don't show us how exactly you created `frames`, but it's safe to assume that it's an array of 8bit unsigned integers. To solve the problem, simply convert it to the right data type -- i.e. make the first argument of `cv.dnn.blobFromImages` be `np.float32(frames)`.